# Bad Disk performance after moving from Ubuntu to Centos 7

Tags: performance, ubuntu, io, centos, gzip

Relatively old Dell R620 server (32 cores / 128GB RAM) was working perfect for years with Ubuntu. Plain OS install, no Virtualization.

```
2 system disks in mirror (XFS)
6 RAID 5 disks for /var (XFS)
```

server is used for a nightly check of a MySQL Xtrabackup file.

Before the format and move to Centos 7 the process would finish by 08:00, Now running late at noon.

99% of the job is opening a large tar.gz file.

**htop :** there are only two processes doing something :

```
1. gzip -d : about 20% CPU
2. tar zxf Xtrabackup.tar.gz : about 4-7% CPU
```

**iotop :**  it's steady at around 3M/s (Read) / 20-25 M/s (Write) which is about 25% of what i would expect at minimum.

**Memory :** Used : 1GB of 128GB

Server is fully updated both OS / HW / Firmware including the disks firmware.
IDRAC shows no problems.

Bottom line : Server is not working hard (to say the least) but performance is way off.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**vmstat**

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 2  2      0 469072      0 130362040    0    0    57   341    0    0  0  0 98  2  0
 0  2      0 456916      0 130374568    0    0  3328 24576 1176 3241  2  1 94  4  0
```

Comment: check with `vmstat` and also consider the difference in filesystems (if any)

Comment: Hi, Not sure what to check with vmstat. File system is XFS. I have added vmstat info to the main question body.

Comment: Seems like you have concurrent processes which "fight" for resource (the column b). And do not rely on first line as this is average from the start of the OS. get second line: `vmstat 1 2`

Comment: Updated with vmstat 1 2

Comment: this doesn't belong here, best ask for it to be moved to a more appropriate site.

Answer (score 0):

You have blocked processes and also io operations (around 20MB/s). And this mean for me you have few processes which concurrently access disc resources. What you can do to improve the performance is instead of

```
tar zxf Xtrabackup.tar.gz
```

use

```
gzip -d Xtrabackup.tar.gz|tar xvf -
```

The second add parallelism and can benefit from multy processor, You can also benefit from increase of the pipe (fifo) buffer. Check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353761/101265) for some ideas

Also consider to tune filesystem where are stored output files of `tar`